# Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 has inconsistent connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, router, drivers

So, I got a new Toshiba L50-B-103 (Windows 8.1 64-bit, [specs](http://www.toshiba.eu/laptops/satellite/satellite-p50-b/satellite-p50-b-103/)) which comes in with the wireless card indicated in the title, Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160. I use this computer mainly for gaming, and I've noticed that the connection doesn't seem too stable as, every now and then, the connection stutters for a second, causing in-game lag.

Because I lack knowledge of the proper software to diagnose these issues, the only things I can say about the issue, when it happens, are:

- TeamSpeak connection quality reports an increase by 800% (!) in the latency, and the packet loss increases to 30% (note: the server is located on my LAN, so the ping is usually 1 to 2 ms);
- Online games report ping increase as well, and may show that the connection is loss for the second (CS:GO, LoL).
- Web browsing simply hangs for a couple seconds (YouTube suddenly stops buffering, Facebook loses connection to the server).

The connection is always strong and I'm located in a room with no other electronic devices (to avoid interferences), no farther than 2 meters from the router.

I've tried updating the BIOS, updating the drivers from Toshiba (which has the policy of publishing the drivers for their own machines), updating the drivers directly from Intel (which were clearly more recent, despite not solving the issue), changing routers and replacing the laptop.

My main router is a Hitron BVW-3653, which is the ISP modem as well. The second one is a SMCWBR14-GR, which was used getting the Hitron into bridge mode and stopping all its router activity.

I have more machines in my network, namely a Toshiba L650-11E (Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, with the wireless card being BCM2070 integrated in BCM94313), and it has literally 0 problems with the connection.

I'd like some help as where should I start to solve this problem, like any actual software to extensively diagnose the connection (and do the same to the other machine, to have a comparison), or, if not possible, a different approach to the problem (getting a new ac router due to incompabilities--merely speculation).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For testing purposes, did you try connecting witn an ethernet cable instead of wireless to ensure its the wireless card thats the issue?

Comment: Never mind, that's what Guest said.

Comment: Run a continuous ping to determine if connection is completely lost or just slowed down: click start and type ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Comment: I did the ping test wirelessly and it averaged 55, maxing 88 and losing 3 packets out of 120. Ran it again via ethernet and got 55 average again, 74 max. and lost 0 packets out of 120 again.

Comment: How about running the ping while gaming? Specifically look at the results while the problem is happening.

Comment: Not clear on your comment: did you test with ethernet cable? And if so, same problem?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to comment that here. I did test the ethernet connection for some hours, and it didn't present any issue. I'm going to run the test while gaming (both wirelessly and wired) and have it output to a file. If I were to determine the problem is originated on the wireless card, what should I do? Toshiba reps seemed pretty inconsiderate, ignoring the comments I made about switching machines and testing drivers, and recommended I installed some Toshiba distributed old drivers and last resort, restoring to a factory image (which I specifically stated beforehand I had already done).

Comment: So, played a short game. I noticed it happening twice only, but apparently there was one other time. It is logged on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g9jgG7xU) and happens around lines 273, 876 and 1480.

Comment: Found this which supposedly relates to windows 8, but a firmware issue would likely affect others also. http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034535.htm but I'm still looking...

Comment: Have you tried the stock intel drivers? https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24167&lang=eng

Comment: I have, and I tried it again. The same problem occurs. I did the ping test and it looks worse than the previous one, with the problem appearing more often.

Comment: Would you be open to trying a new usb wireless card?  That would probably be the simplest way to fix it, and also via the process of elimination ensure it is your wireless card that is the issue.  It really sounds like a firmware issue with the card itself.  Something else that would be interesting: do other devices on the network experience high latency at the same time?  You can download Fing on your android phone to run pings and see if you start getting higher ping times during the problem moments.  If so, the router is most likely the culprit.

Comment: I used my other machine to test that, and I got no issues with the connection. I think I will resort to the usb card. However, I don't know what would be a good buy. Can you recommend any good one to me? I'd like something the size of an ASUS USB-N10 NANO, but I don't know if it is any good. Plus, is there anything I can do to report the issue to Intel/Toshiba to get this fixed by them?

Comment: I would suggest getting on newegg or amazon and look at product reviews for various usb cards.  Reporting will be difficult, as toshiba will blame intel and intel will blame toshiba.  If the card is a discrete card inside the laptop, and you are good at  taking things apart, you can replace the internal wifi card with another model.  Note this may void your warranty however.:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short summary

The lags and interruptions appear to be associated with **background scanning** by the wireless card. Background scanning is a normal process and occurs on all cards but it should not be noticeable and definitely should not be causing packet loss.

The duration and impact of said scanning varies according to operating system, driver, access point, and card parameters. In most cases this results in a few tens of milliseconds of latency every X minutes. In worse cases with certain cards, drivers, and infrastructure, such as in the OPs case, the scans can cause noticeable connectivity issues and packet loss.

In these cases it may be beneficial to switch off this feature (see below). This is not without drawbacks as it can cause other problems as a result.

---

**Background Scanning**

Wireless scanning can be triggered by Windows, the wireless driver, or another application. The scan is done both to refresh the active networks list, as well as scan for the existence of other networks or stronger signals to switch to.

Windows may scan for more preferred networks, even if your signal is perfectly strong, as you may have other networks with higher configured priorities which overrides signal strength. The network driver will search for stronger signals periodically, and more often under weak signal conditions. The frequency of searching and switching can sometimes be modified by driver setting such as  "Roaming aggressiveness" on Intel drivers under Windows. Under Linux, the wireless supplicants can also control this behaviour.

**Basics of how it works**

In order to do a scan, the wireless radio has to stop listening to the current network and physically switch to listening on a different channel, for every channel that it is capable of using. For example if your network is on channel 6, your wireless card will tell the active network to pause transmissions, switch to channel 1, listen for a fraction of a second to check for networks, then switch back to channel 6 to receive any data that has been buffered during that period. It then has to repeat this for every other channel it can use. These switches are a very quick (fractions of a second) so as to not interrupt your connection completely, but does result in slowdowns because no data can be transmitted while it is scanning other channels. Different cards listen for different periods, depending on the card's hardware capabilities and driver design. Some may listen for >100ms, the most common 802.11 beacon interval, some may split this into 2x50ms slots or 10x10ms slots, etc. Some cards can use wideband (V)HT tuners to search multiple channels at a time. The process typically lasts a few seconds.

**Background scanning should not cause any instability, disconnections, stuttering, or packet loss.** However, to put it bluntly, some cards are worse at it than others. Some routers and APs do not have proper implementations of the pause transmission commands. These, plus many other factors cause your mileage to vary.

---

In the OP's case, the ping log indicates scanning is occurring exactly every 10 minutes and causing around 0.3s of delay:

> So, played a short game. I noticed it happening twice only, but apparently there was one other time. It is logged on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g9jgG7xU) and happens around lines 273, 876 and 1480. –  Rafael Damasceno Aug 12 '14 at 19:51

However, the OP also states getting 30% packet loss in Teamspeak and disconnections in Skype, which should not be happening. The log provided, unfortunately does not show any evidence of this occurring during the test period as there is no packet loss indicated. Consequently, the log itself is inconclusive - this particular log shows background scans are occurring normally and does not show any actual problems.

---

### Disabling Background Scans

The following information applies solely to Windows:

If your particular environment has problems due to background scanning, you may consider switching it off. You can get an idea if there is a problem by doing the same diagnostic as above (`ping -t`). If your result shows several lines of "Request timed out" at periodic intervals, possibly surrounded by a few lines of increased ping, your issue *may* be related. If your result looks the same as the OP's with no packet loss, it does *not* confirm this issue.

**Switching off background scanning can prevent wireless roaming from working**. Indeed, it will prevent any functionality that relies on background scans from working. These include, but are not limited to:

- Switching to networks with a stronger signal
- Switching to networks that you have set to a higher priority
- Switching between bands on the same network
- Switching to a stronger signal as you move around a building
- Switching to less busy access points or channels to improve performance

Most of these will only affect you if you have multiple overlapping networks (with or without the same SSID), typically corporate networks with multiple APs. It can also affect home users who have routers that intelligently switch channels to avoid interference - when your router switches channel, you will be disconnected if background scanning is disabled.

With that in mind, for most home users it should not be a big problem. The procedure to do this is as follows (Taken from Rafael Damasceno's own post):

- Run Regedit
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
- Locate the subfolder path that has the correct AdapterModel
- In that subfolder, create a new REG_DWORD key named ScanWhenAssociated, and set its value to 0.

(More information here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/SOLUTION-latency-spikes-and-network-unstability-on-Intel-WLAN/m-p/1461523/highlight/true#M5273)

Comment: You are correct it is caused by a background scan; you are not, however, correct when you say it should result in slowdowns. No other wireless card I've dealt with has had this issue. Roaming agressiveness settings did nothing for the issue. I've solved the problem a while ago and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: I should've probably more clear with what I meant. Of course it will cause some delay, but it should definitely not be percieveable. With any other card, I've never actually noticed the process ocurring, whereas in this one, I promptly got disconnected out of my Skype call. It was hideously bad.

Comment: @RafaelDamasceno: I've rewritten and clarified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue by adding a "ScanWhenAssociated" key in the registry that disables background scans when you are connected to a network.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`
Next, locate the children path that has the correct `AdapterModel`. In that path, create a new `REG_DWORD` key named `ScanWhenAssociated`, and set its value to `0`.

Restart the computer and the issues will be mitigated.

> Source: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/SOLUTION-latency-spikes-and-network-unstability-on-Intel-WLAN/m-p/1461523/highlight/true#M5273

Comment: Please post at least the core of the answer here. Link only answers can be of limited value.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is AC-3160.. I personally think that this single Band wireless card is a piece of crap and it is causing a lot of issues with everyone that uses it. Try plugging it straight to the modem and if that works then its probably the wireless card.

Comment: That's probably what I did first, don't know how I /completely/ missed it in the post. Everything works fine over ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Same Guest, Well it could also be your router not proving enough connection since you need 802.11ac connection for your ac card and most routers shot out 802.11n.  Even though 3160 has backward compatibility to support "n" it will be half as good. So you might need an AC router.

Comment: Should not cause intermittent latency issues, just a slower connection overall...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: Disable bluetooth**

I've just learned that this wireless card uses the same bandwidth for bluetooth and 2.4ghz wifi, which in my case, somehow crashed my whole router since it's only capable of sending 2.4ghz signal. If, however, you are able to use 5ghz signals, the problem disappears.

In other words: The whole problem was because of signal interference between router, wifi and bluetooth signals and the only way I'm able to use my home network with this laptop is by shutting down the bluetooth.